# Is there a way to put a custom lightning web component inside another custom lightning web component passing parameters?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to lightning web components and I want to make a custom lwc and put it inside another custom lwc.

I know this is achievable via lightning with

```
<c:yourCustomComponent attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2"/>
```

But I'm not finding any clue on how to do this with web components.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check this documentation [Set Properties on Child Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_data_binding).

> NOTE Property names in JavaScript are in camel case while HTML
>   attribute names are in kebab case (dash-separated) to match HTML
>   standards. In todoApp.html, the item-name attribute in markup maps to
>   the itemName JavaScript property of c-todo-item.

Your code should be like:

```
<c-your-custom-component attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" att3={trackedJavascriptProperty}></c-your-custom-component>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed